# Swift 3.0: Send an SMS Error

Tags: ios, swift3, sms, runtime-error, appdelegate

I'm trying to send an sms and using that code:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: UIButton) {

let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
messageVC.body = "For a good time call!"
messageVC.recipients = ["79161887060"]
messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self

self.present(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}  
}

extension ViewController: MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {
func messageComposeViewController(_ controller:      MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult)  {
switch (result.rawValue) {
case MessageComposeResult.cancelled.rawValue:
  print("Message was cancelled")
  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
case MessageComposeResult.failed.rawValue:
  print("Message failed")
  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
case MessageComposeResult.sent.rawValue:
  print("Message was sent")
  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
default:
  break;
}
}
}
```

Build successfully, but when i'm tapping the button (action to send sms) - debugger is going to AppDelegate file and stops there:

[image: Error Aouput]

Log is here:

> 2017-02-16 14:06:13.171616 Registration[24422:1035557] bundleid: XLab.Registration, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, propagate_with_activity: 0
>   2017-02-16 14:06:13.172031 Registration[24422:1035557] subsystem: com.apple.siri, category: Intents, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 1, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
>   2017-02-16 14:06:13.177495 Registration[24422:1035645] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
>   2017-02-16 14:06:13.180083 Registration[24422:1035645] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
>   2017-02-16 14:06:13.190296 Registration[24422:1035635] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
>   2017-02-16 14:06:13.204079 Registration[24422:1035557] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
>   2017-02-16 14:06:13.296657 Registration[24422:1035557] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureEnvironment, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
>   2017-02-16 14:06:13.316493 Registration[24422:1035557] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
>   2017-02-16 14:06:14.350494 Registration[24422:1035557] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Touch, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
>   2017-02-16 14:06:14.351481 Registration[24422:1035557] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Gesture, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
>   2017-02-16 14:06:14.352214 Registration[24422:1035557] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureExclusion, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
>   2017-02-16 14:06:14.943772 Registration[24422:1035557] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: Observer, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
>   2017-02-16 14:06:14.944254 Registration[24422:1035557] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: Workspace, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
>   2017-02-16 14:06:14.944580 Registration[24422:1035557] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: Trace, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
>   2017-02-16 14:06:32.331 Registration[24422:1035557] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target .'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001107ad34b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010fdf121e objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   UIKit                               0x0000000111a4b867 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 5328
>       3   UIKit                               0x0000000111a4e3da __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 70
>       4   UIKit                               0x000000011194fada +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 90
>       5   UIKit                               0x0000000111a4e370 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 365
>       6   UIKit                               0x0000000111a4e6df -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 530
>       7   UIKit                               0x0000000111a4e1c5 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 179
>       8   Registration                        0x000000010f7f13da _TFC12Registration14ViewController17sendSMSBtnClickedfPs9AnyObject_T_ + 1002
>       9   Registration                        0x000000010f7f1516 _TToFC12Registration14ViewController17sendSMSBtnClickedfPs9AnyObject_T_ + 54
>       10  UIKit                               0x0000000111898b88 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
>       11  UIKit                               0x0000000111a1e2b2 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
>       12  UIKit                               0x0000000111a1e5cb -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
>       13  UIKit                               0x0000000111a1d4c7 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
>       14  UIKit                               0x00000001119060d5 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
>       15  UIKit                               0x00000001119077c3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
>       16  UIKit                               0x00000001118b4a33 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
>       17  UIKit                               0x00000001120a6b6d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
>       18  UIKit                               0x000000011209f817 __handleEventQueue + 4879
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110752311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011073759c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
>       21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110736a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
>       22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110736494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
>       23  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000115a13a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
>       24  UIKit                               0x0000000111896f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       25  Registration                        0x000000010f7f911f main + 111
>       26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011428f68d start + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Please help to fix that problem. Any ideas?

Maybe this problem because i'm running the script on the simulator, not on the device ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: My first suggestion would be to check if it works on a device. The error is : Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target. It seems that messageVC is nil or fails to be presented. Possible due the simulator?

Comment: Thanks. I'm try to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code. It's tested and working well

```
@IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: UIButton) {     
        if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {
            let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
            messageVC.body = "For a good time call!"
            messageVC.recipients = ["79161887060"]
            messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self
            self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
   }
```

Comment: This works, I use it the same way. Naturally it wont work on Simulator because canSendText is false. But at least wont crash if the device doesnt have SMSs.